# C# SystemIndex catlog is not retrieving recently added files

Tags: c#, windows, indexing, wmi, windows-search

I am querying SystemIndex catlog to show recently added files in my application. But sometimes, SystemIndex is not bring up the very recently added files. Do we have any solution for this issue?

My Query is like below

SELECT "System.ItemName", "System.ItemFolderPathDisplay" FROM "SystemIndex" WHERE CONTAINS(*,'"searchterm"',1033)  AND (System.FileName LIKE '%.doc' OR System.FileName LIKE '%.txt')  AND Contains(System.Kind, 'document') ORDER BY System.FileName ASC

Thanks for your help and time in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The indexer needs to find the computer in idle stage for it to add recently added files to its list.